# Java access browser's local storage

Tags: javascript, java, local-storage

There is a LocalStorage API to store the data via JavaScript from a browser to the local storage instead of cookies. Is it possible to access this data with Java? Can't find any information/answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not accessible from Java.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, but maybe you could tell me is there really no workaround or what is the reason (shortly)?

Comment: No workaround. This is just something that's not sent to the server unless you explicitly pass it to your API.